# Converting a datagrid cell to a string in a WPF C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, string, datagrid, formatting

I'm currently trying to get the contents of a selected row in a `DataGrid` to appear in individual text boxes outside of the `DataGrid` when a button is pressed. As it stands, I can get the values into their respective textboxes, however instead of just giving me the cell value as a string like I want it to, the textboxes display the value type like this: System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell: Leary.

I've tried converting the cell value to a string a couple different ways, but my latest attempt to do this looks like this:

```
    var rowSelection = EditGrid.GetSelectedRow(myGrid);
    var columnSelection = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 3);
    string cellToEdit = Convert.ToString(columnSelection);

    customerNameTxt.Text = cellToEdit;
```

I can supply the EditGrid class that I created if someone would like to see it, however, I do not think that's where the issue is since I am getting the correct cell into each textbox; I'm hoping it's simply a formatting issue.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast it to your `UIElement`:

```
string cellToEdit = ((TextBlock)columnSelection.Content).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you UI logic implemented? Things like this in WPF are really easy when you do it the MVVM way. If your `DataGrid` works bound to a collection of entities, you can just bind your `TextBox.Text` to a property of the `DataGrid.SelectedItem`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.MyProperty, ElementName=MyDataGrid}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```